# is using array with meaningful field name values not pythonic for a Python struct?

Tags: python, struct

I have seen several questions about how to implement something like a C `struct` in Python.  Usually people recommend a `namedtuple` but the problem is, its fields are not mutable, and I don't see much point in having a structure that is not mutable, so if that is desired, then a `dictionary` is recommended, which in my opinion, is too verbose - you have to surround your field names with quotes, and, it must be very slow - you have to search for the field value.

I never see what seems like a natural solution to me:

```
i = -1

i += 1
FIELD_A = i

i += 1
FIELD_B = i

i += 1
FIELD_C = i

structure = [ 0, "foo", "bar" ]
structure[FIELD_A] = 1
```

The reason for the `i` manipulation, is it allows copy-and-paste without a possibility of assigning the same value twice or wasting space.  The reason for capital letters is to make these values stand out as "constant".

Am I being naive and there something wrong, or not Pythonic, with the above?

Comment: dictionaries are not slow...they are typically implemented as hashtable lookups which are extremely fast.  Also, you do not have to put the key names in quotes, you can use any immutable type as a key...you have essentially mapped your keys to integers here.  Finally, I would not consider the addition of quotation marks as the difference between "verbose" and not.

Comment: @gariepy well surely looking up a hash value for a string, you have to evaluate the whole string and compute the hash, maybe this is fast, but surely it must be way slower than looking up the value in the array.

Comment: Well, it depends on what you're doing.  What you have there is actually a list, and adding to a list gets to be slow once the list gets large.  Adding to the dict is pretty much a constant time operation regardless of the size.

Comment: Why not just use a class? They would be mutable and much faster than a dictionary.

Comment: @MartinEvans I guess, well, because I don't need "methods", it seems, probably naively, that if you don't need methods but only fields, and in fact, you want to explicitly assign the fields (which you should not be doing with a class, but use methods), then you should not use a "class" but a "structure".  Me thinking C++ here, perhaps naive here in Python world.

Comment: @MartinEvans - classes aren't faster than `dict`. Consider that referencing anything on a class object involves looking it up in the object's namespace, which is a `dict`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative to your code using a dict:

```
structure = {}
structure["FIELD1"] = 0
structure["FIELD2"] = "foo"
structure["FIELD3"] = "bar
```

Fewer lines of code, and more readable in my opinion because you need not wonder what is going on with `i`.  I have actually used your approach above when working in MATLAB since there is no convenient dict alternative.

Additionally, there's nothing preventing you from using capital letters if you find that more readable.

Comment: thank you  - I guess this is a bad question, by definition, because one possible answer is "there is nothing wrong".  I will accept your answer and wait for some guru to delete the question :)

Comment: I think it's a fair question.  You basically asked if there was a better way to implement C-struct like behavior than a dict.  In general, in Python, I think the answer is no,  but nothing wrong with asking.

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest analogy, in a Pythonic way, to a C-struct would be a Python object with named attributes.

The cumbersome way:

```
class mystruct:
    def __init__(self):
        self.FIELD1 = None
        self.FIELD2 = None
        self.FIELD3 = None

x = mystruct()
x.FIELD1 = 42
x.FIELD3 = "aap"
```

It is possible to make anonymous objects with a number of attributes using the `type` function:

```
y = type('', (), {'FIELD1': None, 'FIELD2':None})()
y.FIELD1 = 42
```

But this is still cumbersome. But this can easily be generalized by writing a function that returns a function which will create an instance of an object.

```
# 'objmaker' takes a list of field names and returns a function
# which will create an instance of an object with those fields, their
# values initially set to None
objmaker = lambda *fields: type('', (), {field: None for field in fields})

# Now it's trivial to define new 'structs' - here we 'define' two
# types of 'structs'
mystruct_maker = objmaker('FIELD1', 'FIELD2', 'FIELD3')
yourstruct_maker = objmaker('x', 'y')

# And creating instances goes like this:
my_str1 = mystruct_maker()
my_str2 = mystruct_maker()
yr_str  = yourstruct_maker()

yr_str.x = 42
my_str1.FIELD1 = yr_str.x
```

Answer (score 1):

*" it must be very slow - you have to search for the field value."* if you think dictionary lookups are slow then python is going to give you a rolling set of heart attacks. Consider

```
foo = 'somestring'
bar = bar
baz = someobj.variable
```

Python calculated the hash for `'somestring'` because it does that with all strings when they are created. It looks `foo` and `bar` up in the module's namespace `dict` every time we mention them. And accessing object variables involves looking them up in the object's `dict`.

A couple of ways to get struct-like behavior is to define class level variables or to use `__slots__` to define a canned set of variables for an object.

```
class MyStruct(object):

    FIELD1 = 0
    FIELD2 = 'foo'
    FIELD3 = 'bar'

print(MyStruct.FIELD2)
s = MyStruct()
s.FIELD2 = 'baz'
print(s.FIELD2)    

class MySlots(object):

    __slots__ = ['FIELD1', 'FIELD2', 'FIELD3']

    def __init__(self, FIELD1=0, FIELD2='foo', FIELD3='bar'):
        self.FIELD1 = FIELD1
        self.FIELD2 = FIELD2
        self.FIELD3 = FIELD3

s = MySlots()
print(s.FIELD2)
```

These may be pleasing but they are no faster than using a `dict`.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate all the other answers, but they don't really answer the question.  The question is posed "what's wrong with my code", not "what is the best way to code xyz".

What's wrong, as I found out, is that, I am introducing a set of "global" constants.  If I have another structure with the field `FIELD_A`, I am in trouble.  `FIELD_A` should have structure scope, not global scope.  That's one big reason what I did is sub-standard.

Comment: One part of the question was - if I read it correctly - "or not Pythonic," in the code. So in my answer I point out a more Pythonic way. This sort of implies that, as you say, the solution under aegis is sub-standard, not Pythonic.